# TM4C123G launchpad: How to modify one pin (e.g. PE1) without knowing its GPIO and its position in the byte

Tags: c, embedded, gpio, cortex-m

Please allow me to clarify the title:
I'm writing a function to connect 16x2 LCD pins to TM4C123G pins. Users should be able to select any TM4C123G pin they want. As the function writer, I need the user to pass the information of that pin to me so that I can connect the pins.

Now I know there are two ways to modify a pin:

**Method 1**: Reference the full register and AND/OR with a certain value:

```
// Want to set PE1 to high
#define GPIO_PORTE_DATA_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400243FC))
GPIO_PORTE_DATA_R |= 0x02;
```

**Method 2**: Use bit-specific addressing and reference PE1:

```
// Want to set PE1 to high
#define PE1       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40024008))
PE1 = 0x02;
```

Now consider the function I need to write: the user has to pass two pieces of information to it -- 1) Which GPIO is used (Port E), and 2) Which bit is used (PE1 the second bit from low end).

My question: Is there a way for the user to just pass me a memory address and I can simply set it to 0x01 for high and 0x00 for low?

Comment: I think your processor supports bit-banding (page 98 in [this manual](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c123gh6pm.pdf?ts=1642999269651)). If so, you could use peripheral bit-band alias region to access single bits with unique address.

Comment: I think you should only provide a function to enable or disable the given bit index. I'm telling it because I suggest you not share the physical addresses you use to manage the hardware with the user. Something like `enable(/* index */)`

Comment: @user694733 Thanks, looks like it is what I need. I'll see what happens.

Comment: @CaglayanDOKME Thanks, do you mean that I should provide a function such as enable(int GPIO_Port, int index)? So if someone submits GPIO=2 and index=0 the function does the job? So to summarize, 1) users passing these two parameters is better than 2) users passing addresses. Did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: That's correct. You're welcome

Comment: Thanks @CaglayanDOKME

Comment: You could also just use the TI SDK. It provides already some abstraction. BTW. I would not say just ènable()` .. either you make a module which handles GPIO like in the SDK, which can be used in other modules too, or you provide some LCD module callout like `Lcd_LL_Enable() or Lcd_LL_Read/WriteCmd(), Lcd_LL_Read/WriteData() ... `. Put this in a Lcd_LL_User.c file and provide them over a Lcd_LL_User.h file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is actually a generic question independent of its platform. The solution is also opinion-based. Anyway, below are my suggestions :)*

As the user will only manage the GPIO, s/he doesn't need to be aware of the implementation details that cover the control of the underlying peripheral at a lower level. Hence, you may want to hide the implementation details by just providing some basic functions to the user as below

```
/* Header File */
int enableGpio(int gpioPort, int index);
int disableGpio(int gpioPort, int index);
```

You can also hide the macros that you use to handle the logic behind the operation by declaring them inside the source file.

```
/* Source File */
#define GPIO_PORTE_DATA_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400243FC))
#define PE1                     (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40024008))

int enableGpio(int gpioPort, int index) { /* Implementation*/ }
int disableGpio(int gpioPort, int index) { /* Implementation*/ }
```

I would also recommend using enumerations for declaring GPIO ports instead of integers. By that, you can prevent making undefined calls to your functions.

*That's all for now :)*